# On the properties of product of two symmetric PSD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, projection-matrices

Given the following information:

- $\Sigma \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric positive definite and $K \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric positive semi-definite.
- K is a kernel, $K = XX^{T}$ with $X \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, and $ m \ge n$
- Define $V = \Sigma^{-1}(I-P)$, where $ P=Z(Z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}Z)^{-1}Z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}$ is a projection matrix
- $Z \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times j}$, $j \ge 1$ and $Z$ is of full rank.

I'm interested in the properties of $A = VK$, for example is $A$ symmetric PSD?

Comment: I've done some numerical analysis and it appears to be the case, but don't know how generalizable is that. If I remember correctly there is a rule for hermitian matrices that their product is hermitian if and only if they commute. Then I guess the problem boils down to showing $\Sigma^{-1}K = K\Sigma^{-1}$, is this the right way to approach this?

Comment: Is $P$ a projection matrix? I don't see why it should be idempotent.

Comment: Right, my bad, the actual projection matrix is $X(X^{T}\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}X^{T}\Sigma$, I'll update the question clarifying this.